# VC++ 2013 Initializer List issue

Tags: c++11, initializer-list, visual-c++-2013

I've the following code that doesn't compile with vc++ 2013. Is it a compiler bug?

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test() :
        mTestBuff{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }
    {

    }

private:
    const vector< int > mTestBuff;
};

error C2661: 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>::vector' : no overloaded function takes 4 arguments
```

This compile fine with GCC 4.8 and MinGW. What can I done to remove the compile error?

Comment: I cannot test it with a MSVC2013 right now, but have you tryied to enclose the initializer list into a parenthesis... you want to call the constructor after all. Demo [here](http://ideone.com/ruCGhB).

Comment: it works... but why that work on gcc?

Comment: For the record, the error message in english reads: `error C2661: 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>::vector' : no overloaded function takes 4 arguments`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Test() :
    mTestBuff({ 1, 2, 3, 4 })
{

}
```

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/ruCGhB).

Comment: @elvis.dukaj You are correct; not accepting the syntax in the OP is a bug in Visual C++.