# "No overloaded function takes 21 arguments"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I wrote a program in MSVS 2015, but I need to run it in MSVS 2013.

I get the error

> "Error    1   error C2661: 'std::vector>::vector' :
>   no overloaded function takes 21
>   arguments \vmwfil04\students$\1302273\visual studio
>   2013\projects\dartsc++2013\dartsc++2013\gui.h 22  1"

This problem is affecting all of my vectors I've created before runtime.

What could be causing this?

offending code:

```
vector<int> Double{ 0, 40, 2, 36, 8, 26, 12, 20, 30, 4, 34, 6, 38, 14, 32, 16, 22, 28, 18, 24, 10 };
vector<int> Normal{ 0, 20, 1, 18, 4, 13, 6, 10, 15, 2, 17, 3, 19, 7, 16, 8, 11, 14, 9, 12, 5 };
vector<int> Treble{ 0, 60, 3, 54, 12, 39, 18, 30, 45, 6, 39, 9, 57, 21, 48, 24, 33, 42, 27, 36, 15 };
vector<int> Bull { 0, 25, 50};
```

Comment: VS 2013 doesn't support list initialization of the vector. There is nothing you can do about it other than using c-style arrays and initializing your vector from them.

Comment: How would I do this? example?

Comment: "written in 2015, need to run it in 2013" What? These are years. What are you talking about?

Comment: @JohnnyMccrum See this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777603/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-convert-array-to-vector

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think he is asking how to change his system clock

Comment: Nathan, that didn't work, getting another error now with arrays

Comment: It _does_ work, so you did something wrong.

Comment: It really just doesn't though.

Comment: That's a total of four comments now in which all you've done is moan "it doesn't work". You have to help us help you. This is _your_ project!

Comment: All of the answers provided do not result in my project compiling.

Please stop patronizing me.

Answer (score 0):

Support for these list-initialisers was new in VS 2015. It's not present in VS 2013. So you can't do it.

You'll have to take [the old-fashioned, C++03 approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2236197/560648) instead.

Comment: The top answer doesn't work in a header file, which is where I need to use this code.

Comment: @JohnnyMccrum: _All_ the other answers do. Read them.

Comment: @JohnnyMccrum: So? Are you familiar with the concept of software development? Breaking news: new software does things the old software didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in Visual Studio 2013 as it does support [list initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) ([2013 specific documentation of the functionality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn387583(v=vs.120).aspx#Anchor_1)). Try enclosing the brackets in a parenthesis per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533191/vc-2013-initializer-list-issue).

e.g. `vector<int> Double({ 0, 40, 2, 36, 8, 26, 12, 20, 30, 4, 34, 6, 38, 14, 32, 16, 22, 28, 18, 24, 10 });`